# How to setup a JTA data source in EclipseLink/JPA 2.0 in an Java EE 6 application for derby embedded database?

Tags: eclipselink, derby

I am not able to find ecbDB JTA data source in the unit test.

For RESOURCE_LOCAL the same persistence.xml works. Only within an EJB container it fails to locate a JTA data source.

I get the following exception when the unit test is executed..

```
SEVERE: Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer prepare method
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'ecbDB' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ecbDB not found]
 at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:111)
```

Here is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="ecbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>ecbDB</jta-data-source>
        <mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>

        <properties>
            <property
              name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
              value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property
              name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
              value="jdbc:derby:target/ecbDB;create=true" />

            <!-- EclipseLink 2.0 properties -->
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                      value="sql-script" />
            <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database"
             /> -->
            <property name="eclipselink.application-location" value="./target/ddl" />
            <property name="eclipselink.create-ddl-jdbc-file-name"
                      value="create.sql" />
            <property name="eclipselink.drop-ddl-jdbc-file-name" value="drop.sql" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL" />
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="./target/eclipselink.logs" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: This way this code was working with jpa1.0 with openjpa.
but with eclipselink and jpa2.0; I think with above code the desource is not getting defined/registered.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a step-by-step description I have used to set up JTA based connection with EclipseLink.

First, make sure that:

- GlassFish server is up and running

  `asadmin list-domains`
- Apache Derby server is up and running

  `NetworkServerControl.bat sysinfo -h localhost -p 1527`

---

Next, create JDBC Connection Pool and JDBC Resource

- create JDBC Connection Pool that uses `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource`

> asadmin create-jdbc-connection-pool
>  
>   --datasourceclassname org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource
>   --restype javax.sql.XADataSource
>   --property databaseName=ecbDB:serverName=localhost:portNumber=1527:password=APP: user=APP:connectionAttributes=\;create\=true EmbeddedPool

- create JDBC Resource

> asadmin create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid EmbeddedPool jdbc/EmbeddedResource

If you take a look at GlassFish Administration Console (*localhost:4848*) you will notice new nodes:

> *Resources > JDBC > JDBC Connection Pools > EmbeddedPool
>
>   Resources > JDBC > JDBC Resources > jdbc/EmbeddedResource*

As you can see `jdbc/EmbeddedResource` has been assigned to `EmbeddedPool`.

---

Then, create a minimal version of persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="ecbPU">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/EmbeddedResource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
        </properties> 
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Use stateless/stateful session beans as components to manage persistence operations (as far as I know this is the preferred strategy for Java EE applications):

```java
public interface ECBService {
}

@Stateless
public class ECBServiceBean implements ECBService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "ecbPU")
    protected EntityManager em;
}
```

Use setter injection to assign environment naming context dependency into a field (useful in case of unit testing):

```java
public class ECBServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private ECBService service;

    @EJB
    public void setECBService(EcbService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

---

Finally, deployment produces the following:

```
INFO: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507
FINE: Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.JavaDBPlatform
CONFIG: connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>DatabasePlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
CONFIG: Connected: jdbc:derby:ecbDB
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.10.1.1 - (1458268)
    Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver  Version: 10.10.1.1 - (1458268)
CONFIG: connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>JavaDBPlatform
    user name=> ""
    connector=>JNDIConnector datasource name=>null
))
CONFIG: Connected: jdbc:derby:ecbDB
    User: APP
    Database: Apache Derby  Version: 10.10.1.1 - (1458268)
    Driver: Apache Derby Embedded JDBC Driver  Version: 10.10.1.1 - (1458268)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your derby configuration have a suitable JDBC resource (with the shell command "asadmin list-jdbc-resources"). If not, make one with "asadmin create-jdbc-resource". For help type "asadmin list-commands".

Comment: I am using embedded derby. With embedded derby in unit test how can i define jdbc resource?

Comment: I receives exception..
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0
 at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)

Comment: If you're getting a message about failing to connect to the server on port 1527, then you're not using embedded Derby, you're using Client/Server Derby, and your Network Server is not up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this under embedded Glassfish? If so the problem you are is seeing is because he has a JTA datasource ecbDB is not defined in your domain.xml. In that case Kaster's answer is on the right track and you should create your embedded connection pool and associated JDBC resource. You can use the asadmin command or Glassfish web admin GUI. At that point you should also remove the two javax.persistence.jdbc properties from your persistence.xml because those settings will be convered by your connection pool resource settings.